# How to set geometry of feature as union of multiple geometries

Tags: geospatial, geosparql

I want to organise my administrative geographies based on the GeoSPARQL standard. This question is moved by the obvious consideration that administrative units are hierarchical and nested. So for example, the `geo:feature` (see http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#) **Italy** `geo:hasGeometry` `IT`

[image]

Then I have other 20 features corresponding to the 20 regions (first-level administrative divisions).

Each feature has a corresponding geometry (based on the [ISO_3166-2:IT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:IT) standard they are named: `IT-65`, `IT-77`, `IT-78`, etc.)

[image]

Let's say I have three levels of administrative divisions in Italy, so for `ADM0` n=1, `ADM1` n=20, `ADM2` n=100 and `ADM3` n=10000. In total, I should define 10121 geometries but, in practice, I only need 10000, since `ADM0` `geo:hasGeometry` that corresponds to the union of the 20 geometries of the `ADM1` features. How to formalise this in an RDF serialisation?

```
ex:Italy a geo:Feature
  geo:hasGeometry ex:IT
```

or instead can I point to the multiple geometries

```
ex:Italy a geo:Feature;
  geo:hasGeometry ex:IT-65 ;
  ...
  geo:hasGeometry ex:IT-78 .
```

Would it be implicit in the second declaration that `ex:Italy` is not defined by any individual geometry but only by the full union of all the geometries?

Comment: `countrySubdivision` from `Geonames` already provides such an integration through their API. Perhaps can you use it instead of creating your own structure?

Comment: Actually, the answer may reside in the `Geometric Complex` elements of GML. These are provided in GeoSPARQL but there is no documentation from GeoSPARQL about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to get the union of geometries is the union function proposed by OGC in GeoSPARQL.

Here is the link to the documentation : [GeoFunction UNION](http://defs.opengis.net/sissvoc/ogc-def/resource.html?uri=http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/union)

Obviously, take care of the CRS as usual.